# code detection in a text

Tags: javascript, jquery

**DESCRIPTION :**
I have a text area in which user can write any thing that includes formatting the text he/she is writting.

But before posting the text I want my jquery or javascript to check whether the text contains any code of any language, if yes then is it formatted? if yes then it should proceed the posting process otherwise alert that code should be formatted.. 
e.g here in StackOverflow it doesnt allow you to post the problem description unless the code is formatted .. how can I do that or where should I start ?? any thing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to find some common code for programming languages over the string that you have in the text area:

```
var str = "This is your text and maybe you have som <?php echo $code_here;";

var n = str.indexOf("<?php");
```

if n value is different of zero (true) the string could has code inside.

You could check some other expressions maybe using an array of expressions.

If you want.  you could create a function like this to search over your strings:

```
function strpos(haystack, needle, offset) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/strpos/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: Onno Marsman
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: Daniel Esteban
  //   example 1: strpos('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'e', 5);
  //   returns 1: 14

  var i = (haystack + '')
    .indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
  return i === -1 ? false : i;
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a javascript code to watch the content of the text area and fire an AJAX call to the server at regular intervals with the content to validate against all the rules that you may have. The javascript AJAX call should return a success if it passes all your validations or an error which you can display to the user and prevent the user from submitting the form.

Comment: I already know that ... I asked how to detect if there exists any type of code in the written text